# why i am geeting an attribute error in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)

iris = load_iris()
print(iris)

df = pd.DataFrame(iris.data, columns = iris.feature_names)
df.head()

df['species'] = pd.categorical.from_codes(iris.target, iris.target_names)
df.head()
```

### attributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'categorical'

Comment: There is typo, `Categorical`, not `categorical`

Answer (score 0):

You need to write it with a capital C:

```
df['species'] = pd.Categorical.from_codes(iris.target, iris.target_names)
```